# Big Oh - O(n) vs O(n^2)

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I've recently finished two tests for a data a structures class and I've got a question related to O(n) vs O(n^2) wrong twice. I was wondering if I could get help understanding the problem. The problem is:

Suppose that Algorithm A has runtime O(n^2) and Algorithm B has runtime O(n). What can we say about the runtime of these two algorithms when n=17?

a) We cannot say anything about the specific runtimes when n=17

b) Algorithm A will run much FASTER than Algorithm B

c) Algorithm A will run much SLOWER than Algorithm B

For both tests I answered C based on: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Orders_of_common_functions. I knew B made no sense based on the link provided. Now I am starting to think that its A. I'm guessing its A because n is small. If that is the cases I am wondering when is n sufficiently larger enough that C would true.

Comment: The answer is (a). At some point, algorithm B will be faster than algorithm A, but it is impossible to say exactly where that crossover point is. It could be at `n = 10`. It could be at `n = 10000`. It could be at `n = 100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000` (or more).

Answer (score 2):

There are actually two issues here.

The first is the one you mentioned. Orders of growth are asymptotic. They just say that there exists some *n<sub>0</sub>* for which, for any *n > n<sub>0</sub>*, the function is bounded in some way. They say nothing about specific values of *n*, only "large enough" ones.

The second problem (which you did not mention), is that *O* is [just an upper bound (as opposed to *Θ*)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), and so even for large enough *n* you can't compare the two. So if *A = √n* and *B = n*, then obviously *B* grows faster than *A*. However, *A* and *B* still fit the question, as *√ n = O(n<sup>2</sup>)* and *n = O(n)*.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is A.

Big Oh order of a function f(x) is g(x) if f(x)<=K*g(x) forall x>some real number

Big Oh of 3*n+2 and n is O(n) since 4*n is greater than both functions for all x>2 . since both the Big oh notation of the functions are same we cannot say that they run in the same time for some value.For example at n=0 the value of first function is 2 and the second one is 0

So we cannot exactly relate the running times of two functions for some value.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is a): You can't really say anything for any specific number just given the big O notation.

Counter-example for c: B has a runtime of 1000*n (= O(n)), A has a runtime of n^2.

Answer (score 0):

When doing algorithm analysis, specifically Big Oh, you should really only think about input sizes tending towards infinity. With such a small size (tens vs. thousands vs. millions), there is not a significant difference between the two. However, in general O(n) should run faster than O(n^2), even if it the difference is less than few milliseconds. I suspect the key word in that question is **much**.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is based on my experience in competitive programming, which require a basic understanding of the `O` or called Big O.

When you talk about which one is faster and which one is slower, of course, basic calculation is done that. O(n) is faster than O(n^2), big oh is used based on worst case scenario.

Now when exactly that happen? Well, in competitive programming, we used `10^8` thumb rule. It's mean if an algorithm complexity is O(n) and then there is around `n = 10^8` with time limit around 1 second, the algorithm can solve the problem.

But what if the algorithm complexity is O(n^2)? No, then, it will need around `(10^8)^2` which is more than 1 second. (1-second computer can process around 10^8 operation).

So, for 1 second time, the max bound for O(n^2) is around `10^4` meanwhile for O(n) can do up to `10^8`. This is where we can clearly see the different between the two complexity in 1 second time pass on a computer.